# Requesting header information of a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, video, ffmpeg

is there anyway I can request only the header information of any media. For example I just want to request header information of any video file so as to find its video length. I tried using `ffmpeg -i {video_url}` and did the work but I noticed that it actually downloads the given media in local storage and returns back the header information which obviously increases roundtrip time.

So I would really appreciate if there is any idea for finding the length of media in a fly. BTW I have a ruby on rails application where I need to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `ffprobe -show_format`. ffprobe comes with ffmpeg, and should have been compiled and installed along with it.

Comment: I tried it and did the job but took a bit of time. I wanna know if it downloads the media locally before reading media information or it just requests only header information from the server

Answer (score 0):

You can also try mediainfo. you can download it from: http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en.
There is also a wrapper gem for mediainfo but it didn't work well for me. I just used:
    `response = '#{mediainfo_path} #{source.path} --output=json 2>&1'`
and you can then search the response for the properties you want such as "duration" etc.